# rsync filter file rules for subpath

Tags: rsync, rsnapshot

I have a big problem in understanding rsync filter rules for sub path.
I have this directory tree:

```
|-- index.php
|-- other-file-php.php
|-- filesource.php
|   |-- album1
|   |   |-- firstphoto.jpg
|   |   |-- second.jpg
|   |   |-- index.php
|   |   `-- thumbs
|   |       |-- _map.txt
|   |       |-- _title_ciao.jpg.txt
|   |       |-- _120_second.jpg
|   |       |-- _dir_album1.jpg
|   |       `-- _300_second.jpg
|   |-- altre
|   |   |-- img_1172.jpg
|   |   |-- album2
|   |   |   |-- index.php
|   |   |   `-- thumbs
|   |   |       |-- _title_img_1172.jpg.txt
|   |   |       |-- _dir_album2.jpg
|   |   |       `-- _guestbook.html
```

I can only use option -f -filter of rsync, because I must write all rules into one file.
In this tree there are different types of files that can be at any level of the tree. I want to:

1. have a full backup of the directory structure
2. backup all files of type `.php`, `.txt`, `.html`
3. backup `.jpg` files that *do not* begin with `_`
4. backup `.jpg` files that start with `_dir`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your points:

1. This just means that all exclusion rules you specify must be files, and not directories.  Since rsync doesn't distinguish on type, you've got to be careful with your rules (and file naming conventions).
2. Use:

   ```
   + **/*.php
   + **/*.txt
   + **/*.html
   ```
3. Use:

   ```
   + **/*.jpg
   - **/_*.jpg
   ```
4. I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: IMHO, the "\*\*/*.php" notation is redundant (as similar ones). It should be enough to write "\*.php" - this is checked for every file in all subdirectories (for files at the head of transfer that would be "/\*.php", with the leading slash).

Answer (score 5):

Put the following lines into `filter.txt`:

```
+ */
+ *.php
+ *.txt
+ *.html
+ **/_dir*.jpg
- **/_*.jpg
+ *.jpg
- *
```

Then run `rsync` like this:

```
rsync -a --include-from=filter.txt /path/to/source/ /path/to/dest
```

Explanation of `filter.txt`:

First of all, note that the ordering of the filter rules is very important, since `rsync` evaluates them in order and applies **the first rule that matches**.

By default, `rsync` includes all files that are not explicitly excluded, so the final rule in `filter.txt` is to exclude everything that wasn't explicitly included by the preceding rules. The first rule includes all directories (as indicated by the trailing `/`), which should take care of your #1 condition. Rules 2 thru 4 handle php, txt, and html files, respectively, while rules 5 thru 7 allow all jpg files that either start with `_dir`, or otherwise do not start with `_`.

(Rules 5 and 6 have the `**` prefix in order to anchor the wildcard rules to the beginning of a filename part **at any directory depth**. Without the `**` prefix, those rules would only match at the top level source directory.)

Final note: If you are unable (for some reason) to use `--include-from`, then you should be able to specify the filter rules as a series of `-f` options on the command line.

**EDIT**

To use `filter.txt` in `rsnapshot`, you can specify it in `rsnapshot.conf` via the `include_file` parameter, as follows:

```
include_file /path/to/filter.txt
```

**EDIT #2**

If you need to use a different set of filters for each backup, you can use a different `include_file` for each `backup` line in your `rsnapshot.conf`, e.g.:

```
...
backup /path/to/src1/ dest1/ include_file=/path/to/src1_filter.txt
backup /path/to/src2/ dest2/ include_file=/path/to/src2_filter.txt
...
```

Comment: tnk! but the problem is that I can only use option -f -filter of rsync. Because passing this option value by Rsnapshot

Comment: Well then, check the `rsnapshot` man page. The `include_file` parameter in `rsnapshot.conf` allows you specify a file name that gets passed directly to `rsync` via `--include-from`. (See my edit.)

Comment: Actually, yes, you can use a different `include_file` for each `backup` rule. See my second edit.

Comment: However, before the path of filter is necessary "include_file=._/path/src.."

Answer (score -1):

Best for you is to make file you will use with option: `--files-from` using find command, like that:

```
cd dirtobackup;find . |egrep '\.php$|\.txt$|\.html$|^[^_].*\.jpg$|^_dir.*\.jpg$' >/tmp/files_tobackup
rsync --files-from=/tmp/files_tobackup dirtubackup dst
```

Comment: sorry but I can only use option -f -filter of rsync. and i have many many files... a find command would slow

Comment: find will be same slow as rsync, as you still need to recursive crawl whole dir